# How to upload and install Python Library using Github repository

Tags: python, github, pip, pypi

I need to upload my python library on Github repository and try to install it using

> pip install my repository name

How can I do that?

> Note: I add setup.py, Licence.txt and Manifest.in files to

It is installing only info file this is the repository:
https://github.com/zieadshabkalieh/oauth2clientz

Comment: Unless you are specifically asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/distributing/index.html, https://packaging.python.org/, https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+how+to+create+package

Answer (score 0):

in this way you can install `python` package from `Github` repository:

```
pip install "git+https://github.com/your_repository_name"
```

Comment: It is installing only info file not the library @hmn Falahi

Comment: That probably means your `setup.py` is flawed.

Comment: @tripleee maybe this is the problem but I make the setup.py like I learned from the documentation is there any thing wrong this is my setup.py file:

https://github.com/zieadshabkalieh/oauth2clientz/blob/main/setup.py

Comment: You import `find_packages` but never use it for anything. But don't start new questions in comment threads; instead, ask a new question if you can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up GitHub actions. [Here are some docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/quickstart).

In particular you might want something that looks like:

```
name: Python application

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python 3.9
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: 3.9
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install flake8 pytest
        if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
```

If you want to upload to PyPi (i.e. make your package `pip package-name install`-able, it's a bit more complicated:

- Set up a PyPi account.
- `pip install wheel twine`,
- At the root of your project run `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`
- `python -m twine upload "dist/*"`
- Authenticate, and you're done.